# How do I translate my CLI curl POST api create user call to R httr?

Tags: r, curl, post, httr

I want to [add users to groups on nextcloud via their API](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/16/admin_manual/configuration_user/instruction_set_for_users.html#add-a-new-user).

I succeeded with adding one user (ncuser) to Group1 and Group2 from my CLI, by running this request:

`curl -X POST https://adminuser:'admin pass phrase'@cloud.example.org/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/ncuser/groups -d groupid="Group1" -d groupid="Group2" -H "OCS-APIRequest: true"`

With the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ocs>
 <meta>
  <status>ok</status>
  <statuscode>100</statuscode>
  <message>OK</message>
  <totalitems></totalitems>
  <itemsperpage></itemsperpage>
 </meta>
 <data/>
</ocs>
```

I attempted to run the request in Rstudio with this code:

```
library(curl)
library(httr)

call <- POST("https://adminuser:'admin pass phrase'@cloud.example.org/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/ncuser/groups",
     body = list(groupid = "Group1", groupid = "Group2"),
     add_headers('OCS-APIRequest' = "true", 'Content-Type' = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
```

But this isn't successful. I get this response in R:

```
Response [https://adminuser:'admin pass phrase'@cloud.example.org/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/ncuser/groups]
  Date: 2020-03-22 15:43
  Status: 401
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 140 B
```

Here is the content of my R POST request:

```
content(call)

$ocs
$ocs$meta
$ocs$meta$status
[1] "failure"

$ocs$meta$statuscode
[1] 997

$ocs$meta$message
[1] "Current user is not logged in"

$ocs$meta$totalitems
[1] ""

$ocs$meta$itemsperpage
[1] ""


$ocs$data
list()
```

It seems like I wasn't able to login through the POST() url, and need to add adminuser and 'admin pass phrase' in some other way, but i am not sure how.

Also, [the nextcloud API documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/16/admin_manual/configuration_user/user_provisioning_api.html#user-provisioning-api) states that OCS-APIRequest and the content type needs to be specified in the header, but I am not sure if i did that correctly.

> All calls to OCS endpoints require the OCS-APIRequest header to be set to true.
>
> All POST requests require the Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded header. (Note: Some libraries like cURL set this header automatically, others require setting the header explicitly.)

How should my POST request be written in R so that I can successfully add my nextcloud users to groups?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try

```
call <- POST("https://cloud.example.org/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/ncuser/groups",
     body = list(groupid = "Group1", groupid = "Group2"),
     add_headers('OCS-APIRequest' = "true"),
     authenticate("adminuser", "admin pass phrase"),
     encode = "form")
```

This will make sure `POST` encode the body properly and will more safely pass the username/password. You can also try adding in `verbose()` to get more output. It's not going to be easy to help you without some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) we can use for testing.

Comment: The request goes through, but it only adds the user to Group2. I tried `body = list(groupid = c("Group1", "Group2")` but I got this error:
`Error in vapply(elements, encode, character(1)) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2`

Comment: I would love to give you a reproducible example, but I don't have access to a nextcloud server that I can give personal API token access to.